# How to check in Perl if symbolic link error?

Tags: perl

The following bit errors out:

```
# Only Execute on Prod Stagesif ($stage eq 'Prod') {
if ($stage eq "Prod") {
    # If /mysql symlink exists, exit0 immediately    
    if ( -l "/mysql" ) {
        exit(0);
        }
    elsif {
        die "Did not meet expected system disk configuration";
    }
}
exit (0);
```

with:

```
syntax error at ./010MySQLDataDirectoryCheck.pl line 16, near "elsif {"
syntax error at ./010MySQLDataDirectoryCheck.pl line 19, near "}"
Execution of ./010MySQLDataDirectoryCheck.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What exactly did I miss?

Comment: You do realize that `if (something) { exit } else { die }` prevents your program from continuing past this point, right?

Answer (score 2):

...an `elsif` ==> `else` by any chance?

Comment: please disregard, fixed.  yes, problem was with else :)